# How to disable save, save-as or ctr+c unsing office-js

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-js-helpers

How can i disable "save","save as", "ctrl-c" from MS Word with add-in written with office-js? I need edit but i need blocking  this actions. Is it possible to add an event handler to capture and handler this actions?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible using the Word JS APIs, no.

Even with the more extensive COM APIs protecting a document's content to this extent is difficult, if not impossible. Word is not a "reading" program - it's a word processor. It's main purpose is to *edit content*. For the purpose of producing "read only" documents a different file format/software would be required. But even then, if it can appear on the screen it can probably be "scraped"...